# Transparent jpg image. HOW?

Tags: image, jpeg, transparency

i just came across this image

http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-house-House-Clip-Art-87.jpg

and it looks like a transparent .jpg image

as far as i know there is no transparency in jpg images

how can that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be done. Your JPG image is in fact a PNG. It is only named JPG, but the server says its MIME type is `image/png`. MIME type wins over file extension in browsers. A browser only tries to determine file type by file extension if the MIME type is missing - if there is a type, the file is assumed to be of that type, regardless of its extension; it may even have no extension at all.

Comment: by the way i tried opening it in Photoshop and it gave an error,

Comment: @CMS Photoshop won't know the MIME type if you store the image, the MIME type is not part of the file itself and also not stored elsewhere. You probably need to rename the file to `.png` as Photoshop may only look at the file extension and not try to guess by content.